# split node contents in two when encoutering a specific node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Ok so here's the XML document I have:

**INPUT**

```
<parent>
  <para> text 1 <NodeTypeA>element1</NodeTypeA> text2 <Xref ref="1"/> text3</para>
</parent>
```

I would like to take the Xref node outside of the para node, but I would like it to split the para in two, like this:

**Wanted output**

```
<parent>
  <para> text 1 <NodeTypeA>element1</NodeTypeA> text2 </para>
  <Xref ref="1"/>
  <para> text3</para>
</parent>
```

For the rest of the contents inside the para, I would like it to keep the same structure, I just want the Xref out and splitting it. But I really can't see how I can achieve that.

Comment: In case you use at least XSLT 2 it is simply `<xsl:template match="para"><xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::Xref)"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()"><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><para><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></para></xsl:otherwise></xsl:for-each-group></xsl:template>`.

Comment: I'm actually using XSLT 1 so this soution doesn't compile unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2/3 this is just another use case for `xsl:for-each-group group-adjacent`, in this case with `xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::Xref)"`:

```
  <xsl:template match="para">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::Xref)">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <para>
                      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                  </para>
               </xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuP7

In XSLT 1 with sibling recursion you can work along the lines of

```
<xsl:template match="para[Xref]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para/node()[not(self::Xref)]">
    <xsl:param name="group" select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
        <xsl:with-param name="group" select="$group | ."/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para/node()[not(self::Xref) and not(following-sibling::Xref)][last()]">
    <xsl:param name="group" select="."/>
    <para>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$group | ."/>
    </para>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para/Xref">
    <xsl:param name="group"/>
    <xsl:if test="$group">
        <para>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$group"/>
        </para>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuP7/2

But it can break easily in edge cases so I haven't tested it thoroughly to tell whether any sequence of Xref and other nodes gives the right result. And the above has the templates for that particular part of the input (i.e. `para[Xref]`) and its transformation, add the identity transformation to handle the rest.

Comment: Looks great ! But unfortunately I'm using XSLT 1 so this doesn't compile.

Comment: In another post you said you can use XSLT 2. But that stuff is a bit more complicated in XSLT 1, one way is to use sibling recursion, I will try to edit and show the approach.

Comment: Yeah I changed machine and engine since then, I probably should have mentionned that. Your XSLT1 solution seems to work, I ran a more complex input xml to test it and it worked great. The only thing is that with a identity template (that I need anyway), if a "para" node does NOT contain a "Xref", the output node has double nested <para>.

Comment: What I mean is that something like ```<para>text</para>``` becomes ```<para><para>text</para></para>``` with an identity template.

Comment: I can't explain that and don't see it happen at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuP7/4 so I guess you should better raise a new, separate question with all minimal but complete samples of input, XSLT, result you want and the one you get.

Comment: Wouldn't it feel like a duplicate if I create a new question for that ?
Here is the code I just tried, with a slightly more complex xml test input: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuP7/5

Comment: Please ask a new question with all the details, the suggestions I made did not use any explicit priorities on templates and seems to work fine for your more complex input sample at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuP7/6. So if you have a need to introduce priorities and that breaks something then ask a new question detailing and explaining your needs.

Comment: Just created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450230/identity-template-and-priority-creating-duplicate-nodes-in-xsl) for this issue.